# lubridate convert decimals into months

Tags: r, decimal, duration, lubridate

i have estimated a variable `age.first.union` as a time difference using `lubridate` by subracting the date of wedding `wdow` from the date of birth `wdob`. I got the following numeric vector

```
head(wm$age.first.union, 3)
[1] 15.43014 12.67123 17.34247
```

I would like to have the decimals converted into months (and possibly also into days, but that's a minor detail), so the first value would be 15 years and 5 months. What I did was to create a series of new variables and then perform some calculations. To get the number of months, first, I duplicated and truncated the `age.first.union` variable. Then I estimated the difference between the two to get only the decimal part and then used proportions (e.g. `0.43 : 10 = x : 12` ) to get the months.

I looked into the `lubridate` documentation but I could not find much on this. I tried the following

```
years(floor(dseconds(15.43014)))
```

but I got only the years

```
[1] "15y 0m 0d 0H 0M 0S"
```

One idea would be to get the durations in seconds

```
seconds(floor(dyears(15.43014)))
[1] "486604895S"
```

but then the challenge would be that months have difference lengths. Even an approximation of years = 365 days, and months = 30 days would be more then perfect, but I do not know how to do it apart from lengthy calculations.

One final idea would be to have years and month using the calculation as described at the beginning of this post, and then merge the two variables into the final one using something similar to `make_date` (but it looks like a `make_duration` does not seem to exist yet).

The whole process looks quite cumbersome to me, anyone has a different take?

Many thanks

Manolo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `lubridate` provides a function `decimal_date` to convert a fractional *date* to D-M-Y *date*, you seem to be dealing with *durations*. So this won't work.

However, you can quite easily define a custom function to extract the integer year, month and fractional day (based on an average `30.42` days per month in a regular year):

```
age <- c(15.43014 12.67123 17.34247)


f <- function(x) {
    year <- floor(x);
    month <- floor((x - year) * 12);
    day <- ((x - year) * 12 - month) * 30.42;
    return(sprintf("%i years, %i months, %3.2f days", year, month, day))
}

lapply(age, f);
#[[1]]
#[1] "15 years, 5 months, 4.92 days"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "12 years, 8 months, 1.67 days"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "17 years, 4 months, 3.34 days"
```

---

### Update

If you want to return the integer year, month and fractional day you can define `f` as

```
f <- function(x) {
    year <- floor(x);
    month <- floor((x - year) * 12);
    day <- ((x - year) * 12 - month) * 30.42;
    return(list(year = year, month = month, day = day))
}
```

which gives you e.g.

```
sapply(age, f);
#      [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
#year  15       12       17
#month 5        8        4
#day   4.918306 1.665799 3.335249
```

Comment: thank you, this is very close to what I am looking for. (it also gives me a good example of function, which I am still learning). I have two questions, if you don't mind. the first is why in the return line, days has `%3.2f` and not `%i` as years and months? second, given that the output is a list of entries of class character, do you think that if i omit the days and focus only on years and months i should be able to compute frequencies (i have some 35,000 observations)?

Comment: @Manolo Your days are fractions so `"%3.2f"` prints a fractional number with two significant digits. Years and months on the other hand are integers, therefore `"%i"`. I'm not sure what you mean in your second question; you can have the function return the integer year, month and fractional days, see my updated answer. You can then easily extract the numbers for further processing.

Comment: Dear @maurits-evers and @g-grothendieck, thank you both for your valid suggestions. After giving to it some thoughts, I came to the conclusion that it is going to be much easier to first perform all analysis with decimal values, and then use @maurits-evers function to convert the decimals into characters using `unlist(lapply(age, f))` but only for presentation purposes (e.g. in summaries or contingency tables it should be easier for the reader to understand 15 years and 5 months than 15.43 years)

Answer (score 0):

We can define our own `ym` S3 class to represent year/month objects.  Here we define several `ym` methods as well as extractor functions for years and months.  The `as.data.frame.ym` method is a partial implementation.  We have defined a month to be 1/12th of a year.

```
as.ym <- function(x, ...) structure(x, class = "ym")
as.data.frame.ym <- function(x, ...) 
  structure(list(x), row.names = seq_along(x), class = "data.frame")
years.ym <- as.integer
months.ym <- function(x) 12 * as.numeric(x) %% 1
format.ym <- function(x, ...) paste0(years.ym(x), "Y ", round(months.ym(x)), "M")
print.ym <- function(x, ...) print(format(x), ...)

# test

x <- c(15.43014, 12.67123, 17.34247) # test input

xx <- as.ym(x)
xx
## [1] "15Y 5M" "12Y 8M" "17Y 4M"

DF <- data.frame(x, xx)
DF
         x     xx
1 15.43014 15Y 5M
2 12.67123 12Y 8M
3 17.34247 17Y 4M

years.ym(xx)
## [1] 15 12 17

months.ym(xx)
## [1] 5.16168 8.05476 4.10964

class(xx)
## [1] "ym"
```

### Days

To extend this to include days, as well, we assume that there are 365.25 days in a year and, again, we use 12 months in a year.  We create a `ymd` S3 class for this.

```
as.ymd <- function(x, ...) structure(x, class = "ymd")
as.data.frame.ymd <- function(x, ...) 
  structure(list(x), row.names = seq_along(x), class = "data.frame")
years.ymd <- as.integer
months.ymd <- function(x) as.integer(12 * as.numeric(x) %% 1)
days.ymd <- function(x) (365.25 * as.numeric(x)) %% (365.25 / 12)
format.ymd <- function(x, ...) 
 paste0(years.ymd(x), "Y ", as.integer(months.ymd(x)), "M ", round(days.ymd(x), 1), "D")
print.ymd <- function(x, ...) print(format(x), ...)

xx <- as.ymd(x)
xx
## [1] "15Y 5M 4.9D" "12Y 8M 1.7D" "17Y 4M 3.3D"

DF <- data.frame(x, xx)
DF
         x          xx
1 15.43014 15Y 5M 4.9D
2 12.67123 12Y 8M 1.7D
3 17.34247 17Y 4M 3.3D

years.ymd(xx)
## [1] 15 12 17

months.ymd(xx)
## [1] 5 8 4

days.ymd(xx)
## [1] 4.921135 1.666758 3.337167

class(xx)
## [1] "ymd"
```

Comment: thanks, if I understood well, to get some statistics (say `median`, `count`, `quartiles`) do I need to define the functions for each of them (e.g. `median.ym`, `count.ym`, and so on)? same for plots?

Comment: S3 will give you many of them for free so as mentioned, you need to experiment, i.e. just try it.   For example, `median(as.ym(x))` works but gives the result in years.  If the result in years is OK then you can use it as is.  If not you can either use `as.ym(median(as.ym(x)))`  or define a `median.ym` method which does the same, etc.